# Excel VBA: Formula is too complex for object

Tags: vba, button, excel

This may seem like a simple problem, but it's been very frustrating. I've written a couple (relatively simple) macros in VBA for a spreadsheet that I want to make very user-friendly.

In other words, I want all macros to be run by buttons. However, whenever I try to assign buttons to macros I am getting the error:

> Formula is too complex to be assigned to object

This happens even when I try to assign it to an empty subroutine. It worked, but only for the first macro I wrote. Once I added other subroutines to the module, I could no longer assign new buttons to macros.

This is the code I've written:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

selName = Range("C2").Value
div = Range("E2").Value
cost = Range("F2").Value
diff = div - cost

If diff < 0 Then
    diff = 0
End If
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = diff

x = Range("A2").Value + 1
Worksheets("VIP_TEMPLATE.PIVOT").Select
Range("J" & x).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = diff

Worksheets("CALCULATE").Select
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.ClearContents

End Sub
```

I have another subroutine in the module, which I think may be contributing to the problem? I think this because when I simply copy-pasted my data into a new worksheet, I could assign a button to the routine. I don't think it has anything to do with my file path because I don't use any (I think) offending characters.

Comment: Can you show some examples?

Comment: What is the path of the Excel file?  Make sure there are no brackets in the path.

Comment: To extend on the comment posted by @RichardMorgan, have a look here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/340547-and-quot-formula-is-too-complex-to-be-assigned-to-object-and-quot.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. It turns out that I did actually have brackets in my file path (buried way in there).

Comment: Good, thanks. In my case, it works when I moved my excel file to another path (origin path was some complicated), and even worked with no problem although I put it on origin place back.